Velocity topic in ign-gazebo
I am having trouble understanding whether and how it's possible to retrieve the velocity of links from the simulator. When I launch any URDF, using ign topic -l, I expect to see the topic where the positions and velocities of each link are published. However, I cannot see the velocity. Am I missing a plugin that enables this?
